Unity Vuforia Error: Couldn't create a preview for the target
Here's the error I got when importing the advanced model target database into my Unity project which will be deployed on the Hololens 2.
Couldn't create a preview for the target [5ax] in dataset [PMC_CNC_Machine]. Check the VuforiaConfiguration if you have the 'Disable model extraction from databases' flag enabled.
Here is the version:
Unity 2020.3.44f1
Vuforia 10.22
I don't know whether the problem is happening on the model itself. Has anyone faced this kind of problem before?
I've already unchecked the 'Disable model extraction from databases' flag in the Vuforia Configuration but it still doesn't work. And I've also tried with differents models(even the default one in Vuforia) and it still cannot get the previews.

Kindly let me know if u need any information for this problem.

Hi Brian, the minimum supported Unity version for Vuforia 10.22 is 2022.3.16f1. If possible for you, I would recommend to update your project.
If you haven't done so yet, one thing you could try is also to reimport the StreamingAssets folder after you uncheck the 'Disable model extraction from databases" flag.
